# python implementation of En function for non-integer n?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

The [scipy implementation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.expn.html) of the [En](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/En-Function.html) function is valid only for integer values of n>0. Is there another implementation that allows for non-integer n? Alternatively, is there an expression for En in terms of special functions implemented in scipy that I could use for the more general case?

Comment: Is this the SciPy implementation that you're talking about?: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.expn.html

Comment: @jjramsey yes that's the one, linking it in...

Comment: FYI: The function [`expint`](https://mpmath.org/doc/current/functions/expintegrals.html#expint) in [`mpmath`](https://mpmath.org/) accepts non-integral `n`.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser thanks, will check it out. Need to make many calls to it so will probably need to make an interpolation table as mpmath tends to be a bit sluggish, but that's not necessarily a problem.